# Do we need to call onComplete() of subject in onDestroy() method of activity?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

If in ActivityA, it keep reference to

```
private val subjectA: PublishSubject<ObjectB> = PublishSubject.create()
private var dispose: Disposable? = null
```

Does we need to call onComplete() method of subject in onDestroy() method of Activity

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    subjectA.onComplete()
    dispose?.dispose()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? In normal cases, their is no need to call `onComplete()` of `subject` in `onDestroy`.

Comment: Not required, if you are disposing it. Add subjectA in a CompositeDisposable (you can use same composite-disposable  for all your subject in one class). Dispose that in onDestroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need(and you should not call) of calling `onComplete` in `onDestroy` of Activity/fragment as it is used to issue the stream that the data transfer is completed and when view is destroyed it is not same as completion.You should just dispose the Disposable as Dispose is a different use-case and stop any further push-based notifications instead of telling the observer onError/onComplete.

*From documentation:*

> Notifies the Observer that the Observable has finished sending
>   push-based notifications.

To understand difference between dispose and complete refer below link's:

- [Disposable Under the hood](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/rxjava-2-disposable-under-the-hood-f842d2373e64)
- [RxJava: Single, Maybe and Completable](https://android.jlelse.eu/rxjava-single-maybe-and-completable-8686db42bac8)